# How to get name / value from custom control like the Inspect tool from Microsoft?

Tags: microsoft-ui-automation

Does anybody know how to get the name/value of an AutomationElement of custom control type? Please see the image with the link below. I am interested in getting the name/value of the highlighted AutomationElement that Inspect tool by Microsoft is able to get. I tried checking if the AutomationElement supports IAccessible since from the Inspect tool since IsLegacyIAccessiblePatternAvailableProperty is true. I didn't have much luck with the following snippet of codes and all I got was empty string for all children of the AutomationElement of table Control (the parent of the highlighted AutomationElement in the image). Please advise.

```
AutomationElement sibling = TreeWalker.RawViewWalker.GetFirstChild(table);

            while (sibling != null)
            {

                if ((Boolean)sibling.GetCurrentPropertyValue(AutomationElementIdentifiers.IsLegacyIAccessiblePatternAvailableProperty))
                {
                    var pattern = ((LegacyIAccessiblePattern)sibling.GetCurrentPattern(LegacyIAccessiblePattern.Pattern));
                    var name = pattern.GetIAccessible().accValue;

                    //allChildren.Add(sibling);
                    if (((string)name).IndexOf(deviceId) != -1)
                    {
                        AutomationElement device = TreeWalker.RawViewWalker.GetPreviousSibling(sibling);

                        if (device != null)
                        {
                            checkBox = TreeWalker.RawViewWalker.GetPreviousSibling(device);
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                }

                sibling = TreeWalker.RawViewWalker.GetNextSibling(sibling);
            }
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/78I8g.png

Answer (score 0):

To get the **NameProperty** use this:

> object temp = yourElement.GetCurrentPropertyValue(AutomationElement.NameProperty);
>   temp.ToString();

*note: yourElement is an AutomationElement. E.g. the IPad's AutomationElement within the table*

To get the value of some AutomationElement you will need a ValuePattern to be implemented. Which i cannot see in your Screenshot. (Correct me if I am wrong)

*btw: The screenshot provided does not show a NameProperty nor a Value - I guess a refresh of Inspect would do it (to get rid of many [Not supported]. This often happens if Inspect looses track of the window (e.g. the window was closed)*

*btw2: from my point of view AutomationElement.FindFirst & AutomationElement.FindAll is a pretty handy API compared to TreeWalker - only in certain few cases I prefer TreeWalker over FindFirst/All*

Comment: Hansa, thanks for your comment. The program that I am trying to automate is a third party program so I have no control over it. I am just curious how Inspect managed to extract the text without the presence of Name Property nor Value Pattern implementation. I tried going through the IAccessible route as I saw IsLegacyIAccessiblePatternAvailableProperty is true but I am getting empty string for the name and value. I think there got to be a way to do it if Inspect can.